# meaning of adaptive expectation hypothesis

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this

The of adaptive expectations formula reads as follows:

$$X^*_t-X^*_{t-1}=\gamma(X_t-X^*_{t-1})$$

Where $X^*_t$ denotes the expected (or normal) value for year $t$, and $X_t$ denotes the actual value.

We already know the actual value of $X_t$, it's in the expression. Shouldn't then the expected value of $X$ for year $t$ equal the actual value?

Shouldn't $X^*_t=X_t$?

If this isn't true, then what is the interpretation of $X^*_t$?

Wouldnt a better expression be something like:

$$X^*_{t+1}-X_{t}=\gamma(X_t -X_{t-1})$$

Since we actually know everything but the future value?

Comment: Are you sure you understand the notation properly?  Could it be that $X^*_t$ means the expected value of $X_{t+1}$ at time $t$?

Comment: In that case I find $X_t$ very hard to interpret ^^

Comment: it doesn't seem to be on the internet anymore but there is a pretty nice explanation in a paper that I have. if you want me to send it to you, email me at markleeds2@gmail.com. same goes for anyone else that reads this. Essentially, X_t star is the expectation at time t and X_t is what actually happened. So, I think the second X_t on the LHS is missing a star. Also, if there is some way to include an attachment here, let me know.